# Merging lists with similar value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of lists containing the lyrics from Hamilton with the first word in each list being the name of the person singing. I am trying to combine the lists that have the same first word (the name) in new lists. The name of the list is called ham_sep_list and is shown below:

```
[['1', 'ACT', '1', '1', 'Alexander', 'Hamilton'], ['BURR', 'How', 'does', 'a', 'bastard', 'orphan', 'son', 'of', 'a', 'whore', 'and', 'a', 'Scotsman', 'dropped', 'in', 'the', 'middle', 'of', 'a', 'forgotten', 'spot', 'in', 'the', 'Caribbean', 'by', 'providence', 'impoverished', 'in', 'squalor', 'grow', 'up', 'to', 'be', 'a', 'hero', 'and', 'a', 'scholar'], ['LAURENS', 'The', 'ten', 'dollar', 'founding', 'father', 'without', 'a', 'father', 'got', 'a', 'lot', 'farther', 'by', 'working', 'a', 'lot', 'harder', 'by', 'being', 'a', 'lot', 'smarter', 'by', 'being', 'a', 'self', 'starter', 'by', 'fourteen', 'they', 'placed', 'him', 'in', 'charge', 'of', 'a', 'trading', 'charter'], ['JEFFERSON', 'And', 'every', 'day', 'while', 'slaves', 'were', 'being', 'slaughtered', 'and', 'carte', 'd', 'away', 'across', 'the', 'waves', 'he', 'struggled', 'and', 'kept', 'his', 'guard', 'up', 'Inside', 'he', 'was', 'longing', 'for', 'something', 'to', 'be', 'a', 'part', 'of', 'the', 'brother', 'was', 'ready', 'to', 'beg', 'steal', 'borrow', 'or', 'barter'], ['MADISON', 'Then', 'a', 'hurricane', 'came', 'and', 'devastation', 'reigned', 'our', 'man', 'saw', 'his', 'future', 'drip', 'dripping', 'down', 'the', 'drain', 'put', 'a', 'pencil', 'to', 'his', 'temple', 'connected', 'it', 'to', 'his', 'brain', 'and', 'he', 'wrote', 'his', 'first', 'refrain', 'a', 'testament', 'to', 'his', 'pain'], ['BURR', 'Well', 'the', 'word', 'got', 'around', 'they', 'said', 'ﬁThis', 'kid', 'is', 'insane', 'manﬂ', 'took', 'up', 'a', 'collection', 'just', 'to', 'send', 'him', 'to', 'the', 'mainland', 'ﬁGet', 'your', 'education', 'don™t', 'forget', 'from', 'whence', 'you', 'came', 'and', 'the', 'world', 'is', 'gonna', 'know', 'your', 'name', 'What™s', 'your', 'name', 'manﬂ'], ['HAMILTON', 'Alexander', 'Hamilton', 'My', 'name', 'is', 'Alexander', 'Hamilton', 'And', 'there™s', 'a', 'million', 'things', 'I', 'haven™t', 'done', 'but', 'just', 'you', 'wait', 'just', 'you', 'wait']]

ham_sep_list1 = collections.defaultdict(list)

for name, words in ham_sep_list:

    ham_sep_list[name].append(ham_sep_list)

print(ham_sep_list1)
```

I think I am looking for a solution similar to the code shown above but can accept more than 2 values... For example, the "BURR" list will contain all of the words that "BURR" says.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With just a slight modification to your code, you can use [iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) as you iterate through the lines to get the `name` and `words` from each line. Then, you can append `words` (which is a list) to your `defaultdict` for the appropriate `name`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lines = [['1', 'ACT', '1', '1', 'Alexander', 'Hamilton'], ['BURR', 'How', 'does', 'a', 'bastard', 'orphan', 'son', 'of', 'a', 'whore', 'and', 'a', 'Scotsman', 'dropped', 'in', 'the', 'middle', 'of', 'a', 'forgotten', 'spot', 'in', 'the', 'Caribbean', 'by', 'providence', 'impoverished', 'in', 'squalor', 'grow', 'up', 'to', 'be', 'a', 'hero', 'and', 'a', 'scholar'], ['LAURENS', 'The', 'ten', 'dollar', 'founding', 'father', 'without', 'a', 'father', 'got', 'a', 'lot', 'farther', 'by', 'working', 'a', 'lot', 'harder', 'by', 'being', 'a', 'lot', 'smarter', 'by', 'being', 'a', 'self', 'starter', 'by', 'fourteen', 'they', 'placed', 'him', 'in', 'charge', 'of', 'a', 'trading', 'charter'], ['JEFFERSON', 'And', 'every', 'day', 'while', 'slaves', 'were', 'being', 'slaughtered', 'and', 'carte', 'd', 'away', 'across', 'the', 'waves', 'he', 'struggled', 'and', 'kept', 'his', 'guard', 'up', 'Inside', 'he', 'was', 'longing', 'for', 'something', 'to', 'be', 'a', 'part', 'of', 'the', 'brother', 'was', 'ready', 'to', 'beg', 'steal', 'borrow', 'or', 'barter'], ['MADISON', 'Then', 'a', 'hurricane', 'came', 'and', 'devastation', 'reigned', 'our', 'man', 'saw', 'his', 'future', 'drip', 'dripping', 'down', 'the', 'drain', 'put', 'a', 'pencil', 'to', 'his', 'temple', 'connected', 'it', 'to', 'his', 'brain', 'and', 'he', 'wrote', 'his', 'first', 'refrain', 'a', 'testament', 'to', 'his', 'pain'], ['BURR', 'Well', 'the', 'word', 'got', 'around', 'they', 'said', 'ﬁThis', 'kid', 'is', 'insane', 'manﬂ', 'took', 'up', 'a', 'collection', 'just', 'to', 'send', 'him', 'to', 'the', 'mainland', 'ﬁGet', 'your', 'education', 'don™t', 'forget', 'from', 'whence', 'you', 'came', 'and', 'the', 'world', 'is', 'gonna', 'know', 'your', 'name', 'What™s', 'your', 'name', 'manﬂ'], ['HAMILTON', 'Alexander', 'Hamilton', 'My', 'name', 'is', 'Alexander', 'Hamilton', 'And', 'there™s', 'a', 'million', 'things', 'I', 'haven™t', 'done', 'but', 'just', 'you', 'wait', 'just', 'you', 'wait']]
ham_sep_list = defaultdict(list)

for name, *words in lines:
    ham_sep_list[name].append(words)

print(ham_sep_list)
```

**Output**

```
{
  'LAURENS': [
    ['The', 'ten', 'dollar', 'founding', 'father', 'without', 'a', 'father', 'got', 'a', 'lot', 'farther', 'by', 'working', 'a', 'lot', 'harder', 'by', 'being', 'a', 'lot', 'smarter', 'by', 'being', 'a', 'self', 'starter', 'by', 'fourteen', 'they', 'placed', 'him', 'in', 'charge', 'of', 'a', 'trading', 'charter']
  ],
  'BURR': [
    ['How', 'does', 'a', 'bastard', 'orphan', 'son', 'of', 'a', 'whore', 'and', 'a', 'Scotsman', 'dropped', 'in', 'the', 'middle', 'of', 'a', 'forgotten', 'spot', 'in', 'the', 'Caribbean', 'by', 'providence', 'impoverished', 'in', 'squalor', 'grow', 'up', 'to', 'be', 'a', 'hero', 'and', 'a', 'scholar'],
    ['Well', 'the', 'word', 'got', 'around', 'they', 'said', 'ﬁThis', 'kid', 'is', 'insane', 'manﬂ', 'took', 'up', 'a', 'collection', 'just', 'to', 'send', 'him', 'to', 'the', 'mainland', 'ﬁGet', 'your', 'education', 'don™t', 'forget', 'from', 'whence', 'you', 'came', 'and', 'the', 'world', 'is', 'gonna', 'know', 'your', 'name', 'What™s', 'your', 'name', 'manﬂ']
  ],
  'HAMILTON': [
    ['Alexander', 'Hamilton', 'My', 'name', 'is', 'Alexander', 'Hamilton', 'And', 'there™s', 'a', 'million', 'things', 'I', 'haven™t', 'done', 'but', 'just', 'you', 'wait', 'just', 'you', 'wait']
  ],
  'MADISON': [
    ['Then', 'a', 'hurricane', 'came', 'and', 'devastation', 'reigned', 'our', 'man', 'saw', 'his', 'future', 'drip', 'dripping', 'down', 'the', 'drain', 'put', 'a', 'pencil', 'to', 'his', 'temple', 'connected', 'it', 'to', 'his', 'brain', 'and', 'he', 'wrote', 'his', 'first', 'refrain', 'a', 'testament', 'to', 'his', 'pain']
  ],
  'JEFFERSON': [
    ['And', 'every', 'day', 'while', 'slaves', 'were', 'being', 'slaughtered', 'and', 'carte', 'd', 'away', 'across', 'the', 'waves', 'he', 'struggled', 'and', 'kept', 'his', 'guard', 'up', 'Inside', 'he', 'was', 'longing', 'for', 'something', 'to', 'be', 'a', 'part', 'of', 'the', 'brother', 'was', 'ready', 'to', 'beg', 'steal', 'borrow', 'or', 'barter']
  ],
  '1': [
    ['ACT', '1', '1', 'Alexander', 'Hamilton']
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without using itertools here is an option

```
d = dict()
for i in your_list:
    d[i[0]] = set(d[i[0]]).union(set(i[1:]))
```